# shell command in R: C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: r, shell

I'm trying to call cmd command from r via shell command:

```
shell('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\folder\\anotherfolder\\program.exe" -i "C:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\id_rsa.pub.ppk" C:\\TEMP\\test.csv user@domain://home//blt//tttttt//test.csv')
```

But getting "C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file"

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Thanks for any of your hints.

Comment: Try with single forward slashes rather than double back-slashes.

Comment: Does it do it even when you put "anotherfolder" on the root directory?

Comment: No, still the same "C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: If I run it from cmd as it is so it works fine. But doesn't with shell.

Comment: it works with system instead of shell.

Comment: Did you try with `system` instead? My guess is because of the white spaces in Program Files.

Comment: You were a little faster ;) Maybe wrapping the path with `shQuote` would help?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time guys.